# Error meanwhile loading an .xlsx file with openpyxl library

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

Good afternoon,

since some weeks I've a problem during the loading of  .xlsx file protected where one of that sheet is protected with password.

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("myFile.xlsx")
```

If i free the sheet from the password openpyxl work fine, if i put the password i get this error:

**"Excel opening errorFile is not a zip file"**

I read on the web that recently Microsoft change somethings in the .xlsx format but no more. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this issue in the `openpyxl` bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/193/can-i-open-password-protected-excel-files), password-protected files are not supported.

> – Password protection is currently not supported.
>
> – Will this ever be supported?
>
> – no, because it's proprietary MS code not covered by the OOXML specification.

Comment: Hi again, I have the same error also in a no-protected file

Comment: @Lper That's a different question then. (However, are you sure it's an XLSX file, not an XLS file?)